# Do I need to run react-native run-android to run on my Physical device everytime? Can I start only the development server using react-native start

Tags: reactjs, react-native, development-environment

Every day I open up VScode and connect my phone using a USB Cable and run react-native run-android.It installs the package in my phone and also starts the development server. The problem is that it takes a long time to install the package and get the server up and running and it is redundant to do so.

Does react-native run-android install my app permanently on my device? Is it necessary to run it every time? Can't I just run react-native start the next day ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will install the app on your phone so as long as you don't change any native code or add any new native module you will be able to run it again only opening the app and running react-native start in a terminal